# Efficient intersection of grouped pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tall pandas dataframe called `use` with columns `ID, Date, ...`.  Each row is unique, but each ID has many rows, with one row ID per date.

```
ID    Date    Other_data
1     1-1-01  10
2     1-1-01  23
3     1-1-01  0
1     1-2-01  11
3     1-2-01  1
1     1-3-01  9
2     1-3-01  20
3     1-3-01  2
```

I also have a list of unique ids, `ids=use['ID'].drop_duplicates`

I want to find the intersection of all of the dates, that is, only the dates for which each ID has data.  The end result in this toy problem should be `[1-1-01, 1-3-01]`

Currently, I loop through, subsetting by `ID` and taking the intersection.  Roughly speaking, it looks like this:

```
dates = use['Date'].drop_duplicates()
for i in ids:
    id_dates = use[(use['ID'] == i)]['Date'].values
    dates = set(dates).intersection(id_dates)
```

This strikes me as horrifically inefficient.  What is a more efficient way to identify dates where each ID has data?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Could you post an example dataframe (a [mcve])?

Answer (score 2):

Using `crosstab`, when the value is 0 should be the target row . using `df.eq(0).any(1)`. to find it

```
df=pd.crosstab(use.ID,use.Date)
df
Out[856]: 
Date  1-1-01  1-2-01  1-3-01
ID                          
1          1       1       1
2          1       0       1
3          1       1       1
```

Comment: When I use `df.eq(0).any(1)`, I get a two-column response, the first being a column of all of my IDs and the second a column of all True...  What am I missing?

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @namnnumbr then try with any(0)

Answer (score 1):

Find the unique IDs per date, then check if that's all of them.

```
gp = df.groupby('Date').ID.nunique()
gp[gp == df.ID.nunique()].index.tolist()

#['1-1-01', '1-3-01']
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more?  It seems as though it would be possible to have 5000 unique IDs at `1-1-01` and a different 5000 at `1-2-01` but both `1-1-01` and `1-2-01` would show up because they have the same number of unique IDs?  Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: @namnnumbr yes slightly. Because the comparison is with `df.ID.nunique()` that is the total number of unique IDs in the entire `DataFrame`. So if `1-1-01` had 5000 unique IDs and `1-2-01` had 5000 different unique IDs, `df.ID.nunique()` would be 10,000 (in our example with just 2 days) and so both would not pass the mask.

Comment: I think I misphrased above when I stated unique IDs for each date: 
So in the case when `1-1-01` had 5000 Ids and `1-2-01` had 5000 IDs, where `df.ID.nunique()` is 7500, it means there's 2500 IDs unique to `1-1-01`, 2500 overlap, and 2500 unique to `1-2-01`.  In this case, because the `ID.nuniqe()` is equal, both `1-1-01` and `1-2-01` would appear in the list of dates, even though there's not a 1:1 overlap in IDs?
Thanks for your explanations and patience!

Comment: @namnnumbr Oh, I see... You want all pair-wise groupings of Dates that have the same set of `IDs` regardless of whether they are the full set of IDs?

Comment: I'm looking for a set of dates for which all IDs are represented - i.e., exclude dates where only some IDs are present.